# Laravel 5.7 Migration - How to make on delete cascade on foreign key that is nullable

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I am a having a table which contains a foreign key that must be nullable. However, it says it is incorrectly formed. Here is my migration:

```
 Schema::create('menu_links', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('order')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('menu_links')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

When trying to migrate, I get the following error:

```
(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

How can I get around it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both columns must have the same type: `$table->unsignedInteger('parent_id')->nullable();`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Updated Answer**

```
Schema::create('menu_links', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('order')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: @Codearts Dude, either you have got the idea of foreign keys wrong or you have a typo for the table name. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

#### Wait a moment, you are trying to make foreign key to the same table man? Seriously ? :)

#### Foreign keys are made to connect two tables, you shouldnt make a column from menu_links to become foreign key of menu_links.

A foreign key within a table is NOT WRONG per say but I am not sure why would you need some configuration like that. Anyways, if you NEED to do it for some reason, you gotta loose onDelete restriction because MySQL doesn't support it for within foreign keys. Here is the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for that.

If it was just an honest mistake and you meant a different table then try following:

Usually we make foreign key as id of some other table and usually, ids are an autoincrementing, unsigned integer. So, if that's the case and `id` of `menu_links` table in your case is an unsigned integer then you should make `parent_id` same data type as well:

```
 Schema::create('RIGHT_TABLE_NAME', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('order')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('menu_links')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Basic idea is to verify the data type of `parent_id` and `id` of menu_links, they should be exactly the same.

**Being null as a foriegn key has nothing to do with the error.**

Comment: Why would a foreign key to the same table be a bad idea?

Comment: @Jerodev Updated my answer to clarify better

Answer (score 0):

```
 Schema::create('menu_links', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('order')->default(0);
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('menu_links')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Since increments() creates an unsigned integer column, you need to define the foreign key column as unsigned integer too:

Read: [foreign key constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

probably you should try this.

`$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('parents')->onDelete('cascade');`